# Problema de instalación Laravel App\Resource

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

**Problema 1**
Buen día, estoy teniendo un problema, instalé Laravel con la instrucción

> composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel proyecto

Pero en la versión que me instala la 5.6.21 no tengo la carpeta: App\Resource
De la misma manera no tengo la opción de php artisan make:resource

**Problema 2**
Intenté utilizar un comando

> composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel proyecto "5.6.18"

Para verificar si es un problema de la versión, pero no sé si uso la sintaxis correctamente

***Mensaje de la consola***

> [UnexpectedValueException]
>     Could not parse version constraint 5.6.17?: Invalid version string "5.6.17?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te comento lo siguiente, tienes un error de sintaxis al solicitar una versión específica de `Laravel`, la cual se debe hacer del modo siguiente

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel app --prefer-dist v5.6.*
```

> El asterisco al final de la versión indica que el tercer número no lo
>   conoces pero quieres bajarte una versión que este dentro de la familia
>   de 5.6

Al momento de publicar este respuesta la versión mas reciente es la **5.6.21**

Con respecto al comando que dices que no te funciona es por que lo estas haciendo así

```
php artisan make:resource
```

Cuando en realidad al final no le estas colocando el nombre, finalmente debería quedar así

```
php artisan make:resource Backend
```

También te confirmo que la ruta que deseas encnontrar, es decir la de los resources esta en: **project_name/app/Http/Resources**

Ya con los pasos anteriores te debería estar funcionando

**ACLARACIÓN**

Te comento que en packagist puedes checar que versiones existen disponibles para descarga:

https://packagist.org/packages/laravel/laravel

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Perdón, había cometido un error al hablar de qué elemento me faltaba es App\Resource, lo he corregido ya en la pregunta. Gracias por tu pronta respuesta.

¿Hay manera de agregar la versión 5.6.18 en especial, ¿sería con la v?

Comment: @Cragser ya re actualicé la respuesta a lo que buscas

Comment: pues no te comento que la consola me da error de que esa versión que quieres no esta disponible para su descarga

Comment: mira @Cragser te añadí mas información útil de lo que me pides

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias, me sacaste de algunas dudas.